# BeautifulSoup: Query namespace in XML

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup, namespaces

I have an XML doc with custom namespacing:

```
<parent>
 <c1:doc>
   <c1:attr_a></c1:attr_a>
   <c1:attr_b></c1:attr_b>
 </c1:doc>
 <c2:doc>
   <c2:attr_a></c2:attr_a>
   <c2:attr_b></c2:attr_b>
  </c2:doc>
</parent>
```

Is it possible in Python's BeautifulSoup to query for the values of all `attr_a` attributes in this document?

I can traverse the tree with raw string operations or traverse the children of parent in a very tedious manner, but is it possible to query for `soup.find_all('*.attr_a')` or similar more directly? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the relationship remain constant i.e. first child  of a child within parent?

Comment: @QHarr alas the relationship is inconstant

Comment: well you already got my next suggestion +

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, one can evidently use regular expressions for this task. From the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#id16):

> If you pass in a regular expression object, Beautiful Soup will filter
>   against that regular expression using its search() method. This code
>   finds all the tags whose names start with the letter “b”; in this
>   case, the  tag and the  tag:

```
html_doc = """
<parent>
 <c1:doc>
   <c1:attr_a></c1:attr_a>
   <c1:attr_b></c1:attr_b>
 </c1:doc>
 <c2:doc>
   <c2:attr_a></c2:attr_a>
   <c2:attr_b></c2:attr_b>
  </c2:doc>
</parent>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

import re
for tag in soup.find_all(re.compile(".attr_a")):
    print(tag.name)
```